# How to know Font Scripts supported by Font Family in OS X?

Tags: macos, fonts

In Windows we can collect information about scripts supported by Font Family.

i.e.
 Family Name : AdobeArabic-Regular
Script : Western
Script : Arabic
Script : Mac

How to know same thing in Mac ?

To get Styles (Bold, Bold Italic etc... ) We can use NSFontManager support.

NSArray* familyFonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableMembersOfFontFamily: "AdobeArabic-Regular"];

But not getting any info about Scripts..

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this helps as it may not be the easiest way, but I hope this gets you in the right direction:

The thing you’re looking for is/are the OpenType layout tags (sometimes also called "feature tags") where a subset of these tags also defines supported scripts. These are four-character codes, like "arab" for arabic script (extended list see below). As the `NSFontManager` afaik doesn’t support reading these tags, I would have a look at CoreText’s `CTFont` framework, which provides in-depth capability of reading font properties. There I would have a look at `CTFontCopyFeatures` or perhaps `CTFontCopyAvailableTables` and `CTFontCopyAttribute`. I haven’t tested, but hope one of them is also capable of reading the layout/features tags.

Here you can find a list of [OpenType layout tags](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/ttoreg.htm), [TrueType layout tags](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/ttoreg.htm) and the [CoreText Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

CTFontDescriptorCopyAttribute(ctFontDescriptor, kCTFontLanguageAttribute) would be the closest one, but sadly that is about language but not script...